# have parent div clickable with clickable child div

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

How do I do something like:

```
<div onclick="foo1()">
    <div onclick="foo2()"></div>
</div>
```

When I do that and I click the child element, it still runs the foo1() function. How do I temporarily disable the parent element or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a working **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/h5hnV/)** for you

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS (just to distinguish the two divs)

```
#parent {
    background-color: black;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
}

#child {
    position:relative;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    top:160px;
    left:160px;
}
```

JavaScript ( include jQuery )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#child').click(function() {
        alert('Child');
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('#parent').click(function() {
        alert('Parent');
    });
});
```

When you click on the child ONLY the action from the child is getting actioned. 
You can modify my example as you like to achieve what you need.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery, you can use this: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, jQuery can solve your problem. See the code below:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function a()
{
    alert('parent');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div2').click(function(e){alert('child');e.stopPropagation();})
})
</script>
<div onclick="a();" style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid red">
    <div id="div2" style="height:85px;width:85px;border:1px solid green">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any JS error? Check jquery path and make sure it is included in the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
<div onclick="foo1(event)">
    parent
    <div onclick="foo2(event)">child</div>
</div>
```

And

```
function foo1(e){
    console.log('foo1', e)
}

function foo2(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('foo2', e)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/emreA/)